# Scrollbar for TabItem

Tags: java, swt, tabitem

I am having a Group in Tabfolder Properties- where the set of controls are placed...Now i need the scrollbar for this specific TabItem where controls are placed...

Tried with scrollableComposite but it didn't work...How i need to progress...

```
protected void setControls(Composite parent)
{


    ScrolledComposite s1 = new ScrolledComposite(parent,SWT.V_SCROLL  |SWT.H_SCROLL);
    s1.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        s1.setExpandVertical(true);     


    OptionGroup = new Group(s1, SWT.None);
    OptionGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 2, 1));
    OptionGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    final GridLayout gl_fileOptionGroup1 = new GridLayout();
    gl_fileOptionGroup1.numColumns = 2;
    OptionGroup.setLayout(gl_fileOptionGroup1);
                                          ::::
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
s1.setSize(s1.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```